# Using spatie/browsershot get Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Manipulations' not found error

Tags: laravel-5

Using  pluhttps://github.com/spatie/browsershot I try to save html content to jpg file and I need to set rendered image in 
full height(content can be in several pages in pdf file is generated).
Is there is way for it, as default generated image is cut by height.

I tried by :

```
    use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;
    ...
    Browsershot::html( htmlspecialchars_decode($content) )
        ->showBackground()
        ->fit(\Manipulations::FIT_CONTAIN, 200, 200)
        ->save($save_to_file);
```

and got error :

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Manipulations' not found
```

Which declarations did I miss? I did not find have I to add any devlarations into config/app.php ?

```
composer.json :
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "spatie/browsershot": "^3.27",
        "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.4",

package.json:
    "dependencies": {
        "puppeteer": "^1.14.0",
        "pusher-js": "^4.3.1"
    }
```

Comment: Manipulations is one of your Model?

Comment: No, it is mentioned here https://github.com/spatie/browsershot, but without any ref

Comment: your missing the path of Manipulations class, please check my asnwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the package `spatie/browsershot` has a dependency [spatie/image](https://github.com/spatie/image) package.

to fix your problem, you should add the path to `Manipulations` class into your controller :

```
use Spatie\Image\Manipulations;
```